# Is it possible to deploy Python Azure Function on Windows OS Image

Tags: python, azure, function, azure-functions

I have successfully installed a Python Function on a Linux VM, but due to some dependencies I need it to be deployed on Windows. It is set to be deployed on Linux, but is it possible to deploy it on Windows VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time no, Python Functions are only supported in App Service Plans using Linux.

> Your Azure Function App has 'FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME' set to 'dotnet'
>   while your local project is set to 'python'. You can pass --force to
>   update your Azure app with 'python' as a 'FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME'
>
> C:\Users\-----\source\repos\func\MyFunctionProj>func azure functionapp publish pyfunc1 --force
>
> Setting 'FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME' to 'python' because --force was
>   passed Getting site publishing info... Publishing Python functions is
>   only supported for Linux FunctionApps

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to deploy an AWS Python Lambda on a Windows VM?

Comment: I believe so, yes, but I haven't tested.